# Barplot in Ggplot2: Auto-customized Colour Using R According to the Value of a Column

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbar

I want the colour in this `barplot` to be automatically filled with the minimum figure in `RMSE column to be` green`the nest to the minimum`RMSE`figures to be`yellowgreen`the middle figure to be`yellow`, the second to the maximum RMSE to be` orange`while the maximum figure in the RMSE column to be`red`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Methods = c('b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'), lb = c(9, 7, 9, 4, 9), RMSE = c(0.26177952, 0.11294586, 0.02452239, 0.08290467, 0.41488542))
ggplot2::ggplot(df1, ggplot2::aes(Methods, lb, fill = RMSE)) + # Using default colors 
  ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "identity")# + col = rainbow(5)
```

I saw this online an I am imagining how it can hep me.

```
colfunc<-colorRampPalette(c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red"))
plot(rep(1,5),col=(colfunc(5)), pch=19,cex=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using a palette ("Spectral" from the ColorBrewer schemes built into ggplot2) that coincidentally includes a spectrum from green-yellow-orange-red. (It also includes blue, which I avoided using the `values = c(-0.15,1)` part -- that effectively says the numbers have to 15% lower than the actual range to be assigned blue, so it doesn't start using colors until the green range.

```
ggplot2::ggplot(df1, ggplot2::aes(Methods, lb, fill = RMSE)) + # Using default colors 
  ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", values = c(-0.15,1)))
```

[image]

If you want to color based on the ranking of RMSE rather than the value of RMSE, you could turn it into a factor and use the five colors by name:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(df1, ggplot2::aes(Methods, lb, fill = as.factor(RMSE))) + # Using default colors 
  ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red"))
```

[image]

(Aesthetically you might want to pick other colors by their hex values, like maybe "#70B070" instead of "green" if you prefer certain specific colors.)